# How to increase fog density over time in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

fairly new here.

I'm working on a game where I want my fog density to increase. I've succesfully done it, but i want it to increase over time, something like a few seconds or so.

Here is my script:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class FogScript : MonoBehaviour
{

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        RenderSettings.fogDensity = 0.2f;
    }

}
```

As you can see it's fairly simple. Just need to know how to increase the density over a few seconds instead of the moment it activates.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html). They are like temporary little Update methods and by default each frame the next iteration is executed.

```
// Adjust these via the Inspector in Unity
[SerializeField] private float targetDensity = 0.2f;

[Tooltip(2Fade duration in seconds")]
[SerializeField] private float fadeDuration = 1.0f;

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    // starts the FadeFog routine
    StartCoroutine(FadeFog())
}

private IEnumerator FadeFog()
{
    var timePassed = 0f;
    while(timePassed <= fadeDuration)
    {
        // a factor from 0 to 1
        var factor = timePassed / fadeDuration;
        // linear interpolate between from and to with given factor
        RenderSettings.fogDensity = Mathf.Lerp(0, targetDensity, factor);

        // Let this frame be rendered and continue from here in the next frame
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

or since `OnTriggerEnter` itself may be an IEnumerator you can also directly use

```
private IEnumerator OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    var timePassed = 0f;
    while(timePassed <= fadeDuration)
    {
        var factor = timePassed / fadeDuration;
        RenderSettings.fogDensity = Mathf.Lerp(0, targetDensity, factor);

        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void Update(){
     fogD += Time.deltaTime * rateOfIncrease;
}
```